# what will be the number of rows for UITableView for displaying the xml parsed data?

Tags: xml, uitableview, nsarray

i am newer to iphone application development so please anybody help me.my main problem is

-->after parsed the xml i am inserting attribute value of the xml in a nsarray which nsarray is an object of nsmutable array. something like that...

```
[records addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            [TBXML textForElement:visitor],
                            [TBXML textForElement:uniqueVisitor],
                            [TBXML textForElement:order],
                            [TBXML textForElement:revenue],
                            [TBXML textForElement:conversionRate],
                            [TBXML textForElement:newProduct],
                            [TBXML textForElement:outOfStockProduct],
                            [TBXML textForElement:productInCart],
                            [TBXML textForElement:visitorInc],
                            [TBXML textForElement:uniqueVisitorInc],
                            [TBXML textForElement:orderInc],
                            [TBXML textForElement:revenueInc],
                            [TBXML textForElement:conversionRateInc],
                            [TBXML textForElement:newProductInc],
                            [TBXML textForElement:outOfStockProductInc],
                            [TBXML textForElement:productInCartInc],nil]];
```

now i want to display each attribute value one bye one in every cell of the uitableview.but i do not know what will be the number of rows in a section method.please any body help me.i am giving the sample code....

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section{
    NSLog(@"The number of row in the object array:  %d ",[records count]);
return [records count];
    }
```

tableview method is here...now tell me what will be the return type for displaying all the attribute value one bye one in every cell.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a label for each field and add it to the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath, the outline being :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellPortrait";
UITableviewCell *cell;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

// THIS CREATES THE CELL
NSInteger index = (page-1)*pagesize + indexPath.row;
NSDictionary* dataAtIndex = [records getDataAtIndex:index];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[myTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    int x = 0;
    int cellsize = 50;
    int padding = 1;
    int nbxmlrecords = [[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] count];

    for (int idx = 0 ; idx < nbxmlrecords; idx++)
    {
            UILabel* aLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0.0,
                                                                         cellsize, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)] autorelease];
            x = x + cellsize + padding;

            aLabel.tag = idx;
            aLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0];
            aLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
            aLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            aLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
            aLabel.opaque = true;

            [cell.contentView addSubview:aLabel];
    }
}

// THIS FILLS THE DATA IN THE CELL
for (int idx = 0 ; idx < nbxmlrecords; idx++)
{
        NSString* value = [[records objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:idx];
        UILabel* aLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:idx];
        aLabel.text = value;
}

...
```

Of course you'll need to work the size for each field and the total length in the screen.